# Show doesn't show DataRange

Tags: plotting

I have the following simple code:

```
plot = 
  ListPlot3D[mydata, DataRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .7}, 
    AxesLabel -> 
      {Style[Subscript[t, l], FontSize -> 21], 
       Style[Subscript[t, u], FontSize -> 21], 
       Style[Subsuperscript[β, a, m]/Subsuperscript[β, a, a], FontSize -> 21]}, 
       BaseStyle -> 18]
```

mydata is a 60 by 60 matrix. The problem is that the data range was plotted wrong. Instead, I had to have

```
DataRange -> {{-6, 0}, {0, 6}}
```

Now I would like to use "show" for the already obtained figure to change only the DataRange. However, show doesnt recognize DataRange.

How can one approach to this problem? I can of course change my original command instead of using show, but in this case I am unable to arrange the coordinates of the 3D plot so that it will look like the same as the one I obtained before.

Comment: `DataRange` controls how the plotting function treats the data.  It is not an option that influences how already existing graphics are displayed.  This is why is it not a `Show`/`Graphics` option.  You either have to go back to the plotting function, or try relabelling the axes of the already existing plot.  Or maybe use `Scale`/`Translate` on the existing plot's contents (on its graphics primitives).

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is exactly.  In your plot, you have to specify the `DataRange` because otherwise the axes would go from 1 to 60.  So does it look correct when you execute the `plot` command?  What changes when you use `Show`?

Comment: if I use plot everything is correct. I rotated the original figure later. and also upscaled. these are the things I loose if I replot it with the correct parameters.

Comment: @Szabolcs how to relabel?

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if you showed all of the code you use to produce your good plot and then the code you apply to get the bad plot, along with each plot and an explanation of what you don't like in the final image. Give some sample data as well, even if it's generated with `RandomReal` or something.

Comment: its really not a bad question, but there is not a trivial solution.  `DataRange` effectively takes your data list and generates a 3d table, ie. the result is the same as if you externally generated that table before supplying to `LitsPlot3D`.  Did you really loose the original data and want to recover it from the plot?

Comment: Looking at your comment, it is possible to reproduce the exact orientation when you regenerate the plot.  I suspect that's been discussed, do a search and post a new question if you cant find anything.  (basically use `AbsoluteOptions` to pull the `ViewPoint` , etc, from the graphic. )

Comment: @george2079 no I didnt I have the original data. I may replot it if I can have the exact orientation. Okay let me check those two commands.

Comment: @george2079 great. those two commands solved my problem. thank you very much.